# How to resize Splash Screen Image in MAUI?

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to add an image on Splash Screen and the image size is 512x512 but it is not showing correctly on the splash screen. So, is there a way to resize the splash screen image?

Comment: Its in the backlog. https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4341.

Comment: The maui splash screen in its current state is completely broken. Your best bet is to not use the BaseSize property at all and just fiddle with your image to add some space on each side to compensate for the corners being cut off, and add space on top/bottom as needed to make the image completely square to compensate for random stretching that sometimes happen to rectangles

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a known issue about this problem. And this issue has been moved to the Backlog milestone. This means that it is not going to be worked on for the coming release.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10275 .

Similar issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9797 .

Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with this, and you can use base size to stretch the image in one direction or another, but you can't make it any bigger Even when I set the base size to something really large like 1,024, 1024.